# Nestjs mongo get all data and want to add extra field

Tags: mongodb, nestjs

The problem is when I use productModel.find() the result return from product collection, and I foreach inside to add some property like category and after the response I see category inside of object, but when I override the title and it working.

here is the code:

```
@Injectable()
export class ProductService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel(Product.name) private productModel: Model<Product>,
    @InjectModel(Category.name) private categoryModel: Model<Category>,
  ) {}
  async get() {
    const products = await this.productModel.find().exec()
    products.forEach(e=> {
      e["category"] = {
        // ...property
      }
    })
    return ajaxSuccess(products)
  }
}
```

expect result:

```
{
  "title": "abcdef",
  "category": {
    _id: "908asdkl2walkjwa",
    name: "electronic"
  }
}
```

and the category field is custom add in foreach loop